# How to express lisp (lambda (pair) (apply #'f pair)) more simply?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, partial

Say I've got the following function:

```
(defun f (v1 v2) ...)
```

I've got the following code that I'd like to simplify:

```
(lambda (pair) (apply #'f pair))
```

The goal here is to create a function that takes a list of two values and calls `f` with the contents of that list. While this works, it seems a bit verbose. Is there a simpler way to express this?

Comment: Maybe call f with the head and the head of the tail as its arguments?

Comment: What is the purpose of this, code golfing ([codegolf.se])? (honest question)  I'd prefer this a million times to a shorter version: `#'(lambda (pair) (assert (= (length pair) 2)) (f (first pair) (second pair)))`.  Such "simple" and short code is fun and sometimes useful at early prototyping stages, but it's painful when you try to debug it, and actually hard to read for the next person, or even yourself in a few years from now.

Comment: @PauloMadeira I  partly agree, but adding an `assert ` and explicitely destructuring the list introduces coupling: when you change `F`, the closure will send you into the debugger for no real benefit. The added check is, after all, unneeded, since transparently calling `F` with `apply` will perform the necessary checks (arity, keywords, ...) and give you meaningful error messages. I also tend to think that the meaning of the closure with `apply` is quite clear. I would still  rename `pair` as `args` or `arglist`.

Comment: @coredump, that's a point of view which I would only apply temporarily at an early development stage. From my POV, at the next stage, you should stop using lists as base data types where structs or classes are more suitable, then you actually want that much coupling, a small cost for reliable code. But each case is a case, that's why I'm curious about the purpose, or context, of this question. If this is a common pattern for the **op**, I'd like to know if `pair` is actually expected to be an argument list or if it is a special data type that just happens to be a list.

Comment: If `pair` is supposed to be used as an argument list, then this should be as it is, without the use of e.g. a minifying macro. If `pair` is a data type, and you often need to call `f` with parts of a pair, I'd extract that lambda, or the example I mentioned previously, into a global function.

Comment: @PauloMadeira There is definitely something fishy about the use case and we lack context to know what is the problem that is being solved.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe:

```
(lambda(p)(apply #'f p)) ;; 24 bytes
```

More seriously, [Alexandria](https://common-lisp.net/project/alexandria/draft/alexandria.html#Data-and-Control-Flow) provides a `curry` function:

```
(let ((fun (curry #'apply #'f)))
  (funcall fun '(a b)))
```

Edit: Also, I agree with the sentiment expressed by [@Paulo Madeira](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32964119/how-to-express-lisp-lambda-pair-apply-f-pair-more-simply#comment53757538_32964119) that your original version is far from being verbose. I would let it as it is, thought, because I think it is in fact easier to debug than using an `assert`.

```
(lambda (args) (apply #'f args))
```

... means "*take a list of arguments and apply function F with those arguments*". The meaning is straightforward and the function does not make assumptions about what `F` accepts as arguments. If `F` is later changed, your closure will still work reliably.

Edit: We don't know what is the context of your code and without more information, your closure looks fishy. If you could describe why you need to pass arguments, we might realize that this approach is not necessarily the most appropriate (or agree that this is in fact a sensible thing to do).